# How to search (or select) all rows in selected column in SQLite3 with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to find out how to search (or select) all rows in a column, regardless of whether I know the length of the column or not.

I am testing out how things work with SQLite and while trying to do a simple inclusion check (seeing if a user entered bit of information is already contained within a specific column in the database) I noticed that no matter what I typed into the `row[]` command I always got back only the entry from the first row (as if I'd used `row[0]`)

here is my bit of code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlike3.connect("testDb.DB")
c = conn.cursor()

def createUsr():
    global usrName_
    usrName_ = input('Enter your desired username: ')
    usrName_Search = c.execute('SELECT usrName from usrInfo')
    for row in usrName_Search:
        if usrName_ in row[]:
            print('Username taken')
            createUsr()
        else:
            print('username created')
            c.execute('INSERT INTO usrInfo VALUE ?', (usrName_,))

createUsr()
```

This is a shortened version of the actual code (the other one had more values, but this was the bit that was erroring so I decided to focus on this)

I don't know what I need to enter into `row[]` to select every entry, or if there is another way I should be going about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually select the search results and iterate over them. conn.cursor.fetchall() will return the results in a list of tuples like [(usrName1,),(usrName2,)]. Logically you can use the fetchone() as you only want one username. Therefore, I would do the following:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlike3.connect("testDb.DB")
c = conn.cursor()

def createUsr():
    global usrName_
    usrName_ = input('Enter your desired username: ')
    sql = """SELECT usrName FROM usrInfo WHERE usrName = ?"""
    usrName_Search = c.execute(sql, (usrName_,)).fetchone()
    if not usrName_Search:  #same as if usrName_Search ==None
        print('username created')
        sql = """INSERT INTO usrInfo (usrName) VALUES (?)"""
        c.execute(sql, (usrName_,))
    else:
        print('Username taken')
        createUsr()

createUsr()
```

Comment: thanks this looks good, unfortunately I am now getting `"TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"` at `File "/home/pi/Desktop/Scripts/Database Test/databaseEntry.py", line 20, in createUsr
    if usrName_ in row[0]:`

Comment: Sorry change that to usrName_Search like above

Comment: ah yes that makes more sense, thank you very much it works perfectly now! I will bear this method in mind in future :)

Comment: sorry about this, but for some reason that I can't comprehend it has stopped working again, I now get    `usrName_Search = c.execute(sql, (usrName_,)).fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` , even if I take the code out and run it separately so that it is completely identical to the code above  (aside from the typo on line 2, sqlike3 should be sqlite3) and I still get this error now. I have checked over and over and it is the same as when it worked earlier as far as I can see. (same as in your post)

Comment: I can see from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718385/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable) that it is likely due to `fetchone()` returning `None`, but having looked at the database there is data in there to be fetched so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Yea my fault, when fetchone() returns none, it means there was no match. You need to change the if/else logic. None return means to add a new user with the specified name. See above for the changes.

Comment: Yep that works again. Honestly thank you so much for all your help, looking at how these different if/else statements have worked has also helped me see a lot more ways to use them in the process.